How to include a comma in fscanf
i want to scan the line "Ryan, Elizabeth 62" with fscanf like this
fscanf(file_ptr, "%s %d", name[i], &age[i]);
but fscanf takes the comma as a flag to stop scanning the name.
How can i succeed?
thx

The comma isn't the problem, %s stops at whitespace.

yes you are right. how can i include 1 whitespace to be scanned?

Is “do not use fscanf() an option”?  If so, don't use it.  Can you read the name into two strings?  If so, do it.  If you have to read the name in one go, you are in a world of hurt.  One possibility is to read up to the first digit, and then remove the trailing blank.  Are the example names all similar?  Are there any names like “van der Spuren, Mary Anna-Lisa 103”?

Consider using a structure to organize related information.
Also consider using fgets to read lines from the file.
fscanf and other scanning functions using %s need to limit the number of characters to prevent writing too many characters to the buffer. Stringify the #define's to provide that limit.
The format string " %"FS(LEN_NAME)"[^0-9]%d" will discard leading whitespace, scan up to LEN_NAME characters that are not a digit, then scan an integer. A successful scan will return 2. The name will include trailing whitespace.
Another approach is to use strrchr to get a pointer to the last space in the string. Everything before the pointer is the name and following the pointer is the age.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LEN_NAME 49
// stringify to use in format string
#define FS(x) SFS(x)
#define SFS(x) #x

typedef struct person_s {
    char name[LEN_NAME + 1];
    int age;
} person_t;

int main ( void) {
    char line[LEN_NAME * 2] = "";
    char *space = NULL;
    person_t person = { 0};

    if ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        if ( 2 == sscanf ( line, " %"FS(LEN_NAME)"[^0-9]%d", person.name, &person.age)) {
            printf ( "\tname: %s age: %d\n", person.name, person.age);
        }

        if ( ( space = strrchr ( line, ' '))) { // find the last space
            // exclude whitespace preceding last space
            while ( space > line && isspace ( ( unsigned char)*(space - 1))) {
                --space;
            }
            size_t span = space - line;

            if ( span && span <= LEN_NAME) {
                if ( 1 == sscanf ( space, "%d", &person.age)) {
                    strncpy ( person.name, line, span);
                    person.name[span] = 0; // zero terminate
                    printf ( "\tname: %s age: %d\n", person.name, person.age);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


i ended up using :
fscanf(file_ptr, "%[^0-9] %d", name[i], &age[i]);
the rest of your suggestions is to advanced for me. but now i heared of "stringification" ;)
